# I got this error when am trying view dba_tables Ora 03113 end of file on communication channel

Tags: oracle

I got this error when am trying to view `DBA_tables`:

> ORA 03113 end of file on communication channel
>   Process I'd: 9244. Serial number 1431

Comment: Are you sure that the database is accessible (open)?

Comment: Your session may have been disconnected by the firewall

Comment: Yes Marco the database is open...I can access and everything both cannot access DBA_tables..

Comment: Phil my session is not disconnected

Comment: Check the alert log.

Comment: Is there a trigger that might be stopping you from accessing those views? Check with your dba.

Answer (score 2):

Error  `ORA 03113 end of file on communication`  means: The connection between Client and Server process was broken.

Possible causes and general troubleshooting:

- Network problems
- Oracle internal errors / aborts on the server
- Client incorrectly handling multiple connections
- check SQL*Net setup
- look in the alert.log file for any errors